# Comparator doesn't work for object types in a TreeSet

Tags: java, comparator, treeset, xtend

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate objects from a list with the help of a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator`.
For this code:

```
class ASDF {
    int i
    Pass ref
    new(Pass p, int i) {
        this.ref = p
        this.i=i
    }
    public static def void main(String[] args) {
        val list = new TreeSet(
            new Comparator<ASDF> {
                override compare(ASDF obj1, ASDF obj2) {
                    if (obj1.ref == obj2.ref && obj1.i == obj2.i) {
                        return 0
                    }
                    return 1
                }
            }
        )
        val a1 = new ASDF(new Pass("p1"), 1)
        val a2 = new ASDF(new Pass("p2"), 2)
        val a3 = new ASDF(new Pass("p3"), 3)
        val a4 = new ASDF(new Pass("p4"), 4)
        list.addAll(
            a1, a2, a3, a4
            ,
            a1, a2, a3, a4
            ,
            a1, a2, a3, a4
            ,
            a1, a2, a3, a4
        )
        println(list.map['''«ref.s»->«i»'''])
    }
}

class Pass {
    @Accessors
    String s
    new (String s) {
        this.s=s
    }
}
```

> Actual output on console: [p1->1, p2->2, p3->3, p4->4, p1->1, p3->3]
>
> Expected output on console: [p1->1, p2->2, p3->3, p4->4]

Why am I getting `p1` and `p3` again in the set? Where am I going wrong in the `Comparator`?

Note: This is just an example code snippet. In my 'real' code I can't override the `equals` or `hashcode`

Comment: what about implementing a proper equals method for `Pass` then use `obj1.ref.equals(obj2.ref)` instead of `obj1.ref == obj2.ref`.

Comment: Tried that. No change.

Comment: why dont you post some code which is compilable..

Comment: `obj1.ref == obj2.ref`. Try `.equals()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you break contract of the `Comparator`, don't expect `TreeSet` to behave correctly.

Namely, here you failed to make the comparator *symmetric*:

```
Pass p1 = new Pass("p1");
Pass p2 = new Pass("p2");
compare(p1, p2); // returns 1
compare(p2, p1); // also returns 1 - not good
```

---

If you don't care (or cannot even define) about total ordering, you'd do much better with a properly defined `hashCode()` and `equals()` and a `HashSet`.

If you cannot override those (as you write), create a `Key` class that will hold the relevant attributes, define `Key`'s `hashCode()` and `equals()` and use a `HashMap<Key, Pass>`. Alternatively, `Key` might be just a wrapper that holds a reference to `Pass` and derives it's hash code and equals info from `Pass`' fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you violate the contract of `Comparator` which says that if `compare(a, b)` returns a positive integer, `compare(b, a)` has to return a negative integer. Besides other requirements like transitive comparings. In your implementation you either return `0` or `1` which does not follow this contract, so the `TreeSet` cannot work properly of course.

Comment: Oddly enough, OP does not break transitivity, because he always returns 1 for different elements so `a < b < c => a < c` holds.

Comment: I know, I just mentioned it, so he takes it into account when reimplementing his comparator. :-)